# Android Studio: Activity only finishes when you call the finish() for second time

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So, we're working with intents at school and I'm having trouble with the intents when I try to pass data from the "Activity2" to the "Activity1", when I do the setResult() and stuff. The problem is it won't go back to the first activity when I trigger the event the first time, but it will the second.

I've been working with Android studio only for about 12h so I really lack a lot of understanding.

Here is what I'm doing:

First I call this form the main activity.

```html
public void CheckPassword(View view) {
        password = PasswordManagement.getPassword(this);
        TextView txtPassword = findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

        if (txtPassword.getText().toString().equals(password)) {
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("password", password);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(this, RestrictedActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    }
```

Then, when I'm done from the second activity I run this:

```html
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_restricted);

        lblRestrictedArea = findViewById(R.id.lblRestrictedArea);
        lblRestrictedArea.setOnLongClickListener(
                new OnLongClickListener() {
                    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                        intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RESPONSE, true);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                        finish();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
    }
```

And back to the main activity I overwrote this to act according to the response:

```html
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                if (data.getBooleanExtra(RestrictedActivity.EXTRA_RESPONSE,false)){
                    LinearLayoutPasswordActivity.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                }else{
                    LinearLayoutPasswordActivity.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

If anyone can help I would be very glad, meanwhile I'll try to solve it my own.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are calling startActivity twice. So there are two instance of the same `Activity` and then you have to finish twice.

Keep your `startActivityForResult(...)` and delete `startActivity` in `CheckPassword(View view)`

->

```
public void CheckPassword(View view) {
    password = PasswordManagement.getPassword(this);
    TextView txtPassword = findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

    if (txtPassword.getText().toString().equals(password)) {
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("password", password);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        // startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(this, RestrictedActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        //startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Plus, note that you are using the same `requestCode` (1) for two different activities. The `requestCode` is very important for `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: Wow, thanks.
When I started passing data I added the startActivityForResult and forgot to delete the startActivity, I promise I reviewed the code a thousand times and I didn't even notice it...
Sometimes my brain just stops working...

Comment: @CarlesFitóNegre My pleasure!